# How do I refactor this IEnumerable<T> to be thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I am looking at Skeet's AtomicEnumerable but I'm not sure how to integrate it into my current IEnumerable exmaple below  (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/10/23/iterating-atomically.aspx)

Basically I want to foreach my blahs type in a thread-safe way.

thanks

so .. foreach on multiple threads ... giving correct order

Blahs b = new Blahs();

foreach (string s in b)
   { }

```
public sealed class Blahs :  IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly IList<string> _data = new List<string>() { "blah1", "blah2", "blah3" };

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want each thread to see the *same* sequence, or that between all the threads, each item should be seen exactly once?

Are you able to use .NET 4? If so, Parallel Extensions (e.g. `Parallel.ForEach`) is your friend - it's likely to be much safer than anything I could come up with :)

EDIT: If you want to just iterate over the list completely in each thread, *and* nothing is going to be modifying the list, it will be thread-safe already. If you *do* need to modify the list, then you should create a copy of the list and iterate over that instead.

Comment: I need each thread to see the same sequence. Unfortunately I'm stuck on 3.5 for the time being

Answer (score 1):

If you just need each thread to see the same sequence then your code *might* be thread-safe as it is.

Your `_data` list is private, so it can only be modified from within the `Blahs` class itself (assuming that you don't expose it elsewhere).

The [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class is safe for multiple concurrent readers, which means that all you need to do is ensure that your `Blahs` class doesn't modify the collection while it is being enumerated.

Your example code is thread-safe as it is, but I'm sure your real code isn't actually this simple.

Answer (score 1):

The linked code solves a different problem, you are trying to do something much more difficult.  You have to do nothing special with the iterators, as long as *the collection isn't being modified* while it is being iterated.  Guaranteeing this can be difficult, you'll have to keep a lock that prevents any thread from adding items.  Not great for concurrency.

If that's not suitable then you'll have to make a copy of the collection to provide the guarantee.  No bed of roses either, a thread will now by definition always see a stale version of the collection.